# Gradle error after in include the dependency of Google cloud big query

Tags: android, android-studio

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class`

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.2'
}
 }
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'android-apt'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.critinno.herenowfor"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles
      getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
   'proguard- rules.pro'
    }
  }
sourceSets {
    main {
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/drawable']
    }
}
packagingOptions {

    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libblasV8.so'
    exclude 'com/google/android/gms/ads/AdActivity.class'

}
dexOptions {

    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.nex3z:flow-layout:0.1.3'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'



compile 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile("com.google.apis:google-api-services-language:
 v1beta1-rev5-1.22.0") {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
    exclude module: 'jsr305'
}
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

compile (group: 'com.google.cloud', 
 name: 'google-cloud-bigquery', version: '0.17.2-beta'){
    exclude group: 'org.json'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'

}
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
```

Comment: Have you tried writing 'multidexEnabled true' or try importing only the portion that you want to use from play-services(if you have imported google-play-services)

Comment: yes,I given mutitexEnabled ture...still it shwoing error

Comment: can you post your gradle, both of them

Comment: I posted my Gradle,Please help me